# Undefined protocol error in algolia javascript client - sveltekit endpoint

Tags: javascript, sveltekit, algolia

When testing an API endpoint on localhost with the algolia client, we can successfuly add object to indicis, but after deploying to vercel the operation returns an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol')
    at http.request (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index3.js:6778:53)
    at https2.request (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index3.js:6847:25)
    at file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/algoliasearch.esm.node.js:497:62
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.send (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/algoliasearch.esm.node.js:478:12)
    at retry (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/algoliasearch.esm.node.js:370:40)
    at retryableRequest (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/algoliasearch.esm.node.js:388:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async GET (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/endpoints/api/algolia/reindex-products/_server.ts.js:36:5)
    at async render_endpoint (file:///var/task/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:216:20)
```

Here is the code block:

```js
export const GET: RequestHandler = async () => {
    const algoliaClient = algoliasearch(ALGOLIA_APP_ID, ALGOLIA_API_KEY)
    const algoliaContent: BatchOperation[] = []

    let content = []

    content = await getAllProducts()
    const categories = await getCategories()

    content?.forEach((record) => {
        algoliaContent?.push({
            action: 'addObject',
            body: {
                objectID: record.id,
                slug: record.slug,
                sku: record.sku,
                description: record.description,
                name: record.name,
                hide_from_store: record.content?.hide_from_store,
                brand: record.attributes?.brand,
                images: record.images,
                price: record.price,
                active: record.active,
                category:
                    record.category?.name ||
                    categories.find((c) => c.id === record.category_index?.id[0])?.name ||
                    undefined,
                sale_price: record.sale_price
            }
        })
    })

    // Push content to Algolia
    if (algoliaContent?.length > 0) {
        const index = VERCEL_ENV === 'production' ? 'products' : 'dev_products'
        console.log(`Pushing content to Algolia... index: ${index}`)

        await algoliaClient.batch({  // <--- this throws error
            indexName: index,
            batchWriteParams: {
                requests: algoliaContent
            }
        })
        console.log('✅ Done')
    }

    return json({ success: true })
}
```

Looking into the build files, it looks like when the algolia client is trying to get `url.protocol` from the request, url is undefined. I guess it might have to do with vercel using serveless functions but not sure.

Comment: is this an old version of algoliasearch

Comment: @cmgchess no, this is the new version. Docs: https://api-clients-automation.netlify.app/docs/clients/guides/send-data-to-algolia